# Using xmllint to validate xml against a remote file

Tags: xml, xsd-validation, xmllint

I am trying to validate some xml data against an online schema.

```
$ xmllint --schema https://raw.githubusercontent.com/IATI/IATI-Schemas/version-2.01/iati-activities-schema.xsd --noout iati-data/*.xml
```

Returns:

```
warning: failed to load external entity "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/IATI/IATI-Schemas/version-2.01/iati-activities-schema.xsd"
Schemas parser error : Failed to locate the main schema resource at 'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/IATI/IATI-Schemas/version-2.01/iati-activities-schema.xsd'.
WXS schema https://raw.githubusercontent.com/IATI/IATI-Schemas/version-2.01/iati-activities-schema.xsd failed to compile
```

However, the xsd does exist:

```
curl https://raw.githubusercontent.com/IATI/IATI-Schemas/version-2.01/iati-activities-schema.xsd
```

Returns

```
<xsd:schema xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" version="2.01">

  <xsd:annotation>
    <xsd:documentation xml:lang="en">
      International Aid Transparency Initiative: Activity-Information Schema

      Release 2.01, 2014-10-21

etc...
```

Not sure what I am doing wrong...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately [that XSD](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/IATI/IATI-Schemas/version-2.01/iati-activities-schema.xsd) is written to using relative paths for the supporting XSDs.  There is even a note to that effect in the comments:

> ```
>   NOTE: the xml.xsd and iati-common.xsd schemas must be in the
>   same directory as this one.
> ```

If you cannot change the XSDs to reference the full, absolute URL to the included and imported XSDs, a work-around would be to download the main XSD along with its dependents and access the local main XSD instead.  Another work-around would be to use an [XML Catalog](https://www.oasis-open.org/committees/download.php/14809/xml-catalogs.html) to remap the location of the dependent XSDs in absolute URL terms.

Comment: Thanks for this, downloading the main XSD along with the two dependent files, then running the xmllint locally worked.